# IdentityServer 3 Cookie Options and sliding expiration

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect

Implicit flow app in Angular
Calling a Web API 2 with IdSvr middleware for validating tokens.

It is not clear to me if I enable the sliding expiration in cookie options what cookies this will automatically extend and when. So if I do the following:

```
CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions()
{
       ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0),
       SlidingExpiration = true,
       SecureMode = true
};
```

Does this extend the idsvr.session cookie and all of the other ones? At what point is the cookie extended? Anytime I call /accesstokenvalidation from my web api middleware?

If I failed to have sliding expiration on I would guess it would not matter how many times I call silent renew on the token, I will eventually be logged out because my session cookie will expire.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?